# Thymeleaf SpringEL expression

Tags: java, spring, loops, thymeleaf

I have such problem with thymeleaf template. I am getting:

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "prod.itemName" (main:18)
```

from this expression:

```
<tr th:each="prod: ${product}">
    <td th:text="${prod.itemName}">sdfsdf</td>
    <td th:text="${prod.price}">asdasd</td>
    <td>asddasdas</td>
</tr>
```

product is a List of passed as model attribute to thymeleaf template. I am wondering why it doesn't work properly.

I used this source:
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#iteration-basics

EDITED:

```
package shopbasket;

public class Item {
    String itemName;
    double price;

    Item(String itemName, double price){
        this.itemName=itemName;
        this.price=price;
    }

    void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName=itemName;
    }

    String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price=price;
    }

    double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible that prod.itemName is null?

Comment: I think it can't be null

Comment: Are you certain that you have all the getters and setters for the class? im looking at the exact same code overhere, and its working :/

Comment: Just a guess... `prod: ${product}` - Assuming that everything else is actually ok, could it be that you need a whitespace before the colon, like `prod : ${product}`? Almost every snippet online has that whitespace, even the tutorial you linked does. Maybe that's the issue here

Comment: What do you think about initialising List of Items in @PostConstruct method?maybe there an error occured?

Comment: if I delete th:text then it will be printed expected times.

Comment: What's the complete exception message? Is it possible that the product model is not actually a `Collection<Item>`?

Comment: I think it is okay: List<Item> list=new ArrayList<Item>();
In my opinion there is data type inconsistency in th:text. Do you think String or double can't be printed properly?

Comment: Or maybe something is missing in pom.xml??
I have: spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf

Comment: Is it possible that application just encountered external problem and reinstallation will resolve the problem?I got some error message

Comment: The type of `prod` probably isn't what you think it is.  Output just `${prod}` in the loop and see what class ThymeLeaf tells you it is and proceed from there.

Comment: Can you also post your full stack trace for this post and in the future?

Comment: what does it imean prod can vary from expected result

Answer (score 0):

This one:

```
<tr th:each="prod : ${prods}">
    <td th:text="${prod}">sdfsdf</td>
    <td th:text="${prod}">asdasd</td>
    <td>asddasdas</td>
</tr>
```

gives output:

```
shopbasket.Item@10d9f966    shopbasket.Item@10d9f966    asddasdas
shopbasket.Item@1346081f    shopbasket.Item@1346081f    asddasdas
shopbasket.Item@4c8bc1d8    shopbasket.Item@4c8bc1d8    asddasdas
shopbasket.Item@7b0d2332    shopbasket.Item@7b0d2332    asddasdas
shopbasket.Item@6e38515f    shopbasket.Item@6e38515f    asddasdas
shopbasket.Item@4d9daa77    shopbasket.Item@4d9daa77    asddasdas
shopbasket.Item@5f0a371d    shopbasket.Item@5f0a371d    asddasdas
shopbasket.Item@4d0c8b7d    shopbasket.Item@4d0c8b7d    asddasdas
shopbasket.Item@6112892a    shopbasket.Item@6112892a    asddasdas
shopbasket.Item@41fc596d    shopbasket.Item@41fc596d    asddasdas
shopbasket.Item@4fc03c90    shopbasket.Item@4fc03c90    asddasdas
shopbasket.Item@663e1176    shopbasket.Item@663e1176    asddasdas
shopbasket.Item@13909f42    shopbasket.Item@13909f42    asddasdas
```

Answer (score 0):

try this form instead : `<td th:inline="text">[[${prod.price}]]</td>`

Comment: after reading the other comments i figured that code worked in another environment but you still can't get it to work in yours ...i had the same issue and i solved it by matching my JDK and my JRE cuz my java did an upgrade on its own ..so try setting that first :)  break a leg !! @graluc